# What is the act of cp‬‬ {} ‫‪/tmp‬‬ \; in this command?

Tags: linux

```
find ~/Desktop -iname file.txt -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -size +10k -exec cp {} /tmp \;‬
```

I want to know what is the command after `-exec` and what is the output of this command?

Answer (score 3):

It is a specification for a command to be executed on each match of the find command. What is executed here is `cp {} /tmp \;` that means `{}` is replaced with the current matched file, and `\;` is a delimiter to specify the end of the command. So each file found by find criterions are copied to `/tmp`.